# Regex to find a single character within a python list

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to determine if a python list item has a single character in it and if so replace it with an uncontracted version. The issue I am facing is that I cannot get it to detect a single letter (X) without it converting say boxer -> bocrossbreeder

```
list = ['canine', 'dog', 'X', 'boxer', 'XBreed', ' x ']
list_trimmed = [re.sub(r'\040x\040', 'CrossBreed', lst) for lst in list]
```

works okay for removing the ' x ' but if i try

```
list_trimmed = [re.sub(r'x', 'CrossBreed', lst) for lst in list]
```

it creates boCrossBreeder as it detects the x in a word in the list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex word boundaries to detect if its a single character e.g. `\bx\b`

See example here: https://regex101.com/r/FbtRnN/2

```
list = ['canine', 'dog', 'X', 'boxer', 'XBreed', ' x ']
list_trimmed = [re.sub(r'\bx\b', 'CrossBreed', lst) for lst in list]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the beginning (`^`) and end of string (`$`) operators, like so:

```
list_strs = ['canine', 'dog', 'X', 'boxer', 'XBreed', ' x ']
list_trimmed = [re.sub(r'^X|x$', 'CrossBreed', lst) for lst in list_strs]
```

Also, please note that `list` is a special word in Python, and you **should** avoid using it as a variable name.

I see another answer mentioning the word boundary operator (`\b`), but that does not correctly covers all scenarios, as the string 'canine X dog' will have its X replaced, while not being a single character string.

Comment: I agree with the `'canine X dog'` part. However, you don't cover the upper `X`. Btw, the way I read the question is **any** single char, though I might be wrong =).

Comment: You are right, it's my mistake when writing the answer that I only used a lowercase x. Editing, thanks for noticing and bringing it up.

Comment: Also, re-reading the question again, I am now second guessing myself, but only the OP can really answer without a doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
list_trimmed = [re.sub(r'\b[Xx]\b', 'CrossBreed', lst) for lst in list]
```

> \b.\b

Detects if its a single character

> [Xx]

To detect capital and small both